# LDAP / Kerberos Authentication with ticket retrieval

Tags: security, ldap, keycloak, openid-connect, kerberos

In a context of securing services for HPC clusters, we need to implement a feature related to Kerberos authentication. We are currently using Keycloak to secure authentication to certain services related to the cluster and this is working great. The authentication is performed via Kerberos through the use of the LDAP User Federation with Kerberos enabled for both Username password and SPNEGO.

The feature we would need is the follwing : upon successful authentication, have the ability to keep the Kerberos ticket (TGT) so that keycloak would be able to “forward” it to a dedicated component that we have the control of within our environment.

By looking at the code for Kerberos authentication, it seems obvious that the Kerberos ticket received after a successful authentication is not kept, for instance, for Username / Password Kerberos auth, we have :

- [authenticateSubject method returns the subject.](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/b478472b3578b8980d7b5f1642e91e75d1e78d16/federation/kerberos/src/main/java/org/keycloak/federation/kerberos/impl/KerberosUsernamePasswordAuthenticator.java#L130)
- [validUser method calls authenticateUser](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/575851d45c8c770bee02ef6682def665f0370636/federation/kerberos/src/main/java/org/keycloak/federation/kerberos/impl/KerberosUsernamePasswordAuthenticator.java#L90), but only catches the Exception and then logs the subject out right after.

(I have yet to dig into the SPNEGO code but I assume it is not looking for a forwardable TGT in the received TGS)

**In a nutshell, the feature we need is this :**

1. User authenticates to the service via Keycloak via Kerberos
2. Upon successful authentication, Keycloak keeps the Kerberos TGT and is able to do something with it (forward it or whatever action we would need)

In your opinion, what would be the best way to perform this kind of feature ? I see 3 possible paths :

1. Update the Keycloak code for Kerberos auth (https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/575851d45c8c770bee02ef6682def665f0370636/federation/kerberos/src/main/java/org/keycloak/federation/kerberos) but that seems like heavy changes.
2. Implement a Kerberos Authenticator SPI (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_auth_spi) that would do just what I described
3. Implement a UserStorage SPI that would mimick the existing one with the additional features of Kerberos TGT handling that I described. (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_user-storage-spi)

Thank you for reading.

Regards,

Christophe.

Comment: You are asking for opinions on this site which is not what the site is for. Instead, ask specific questions that might be answered in a technical manner to address specific issues that you are encountering or specific problems that you wish to avoid.

Comment: Kerberos was designed 30+ years ago for point-to-point authentication. It does not play well with distributed systems -- each machine in the cluster requires a specific service ticket client-side, and load balancers are assimilated to man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: You should look at the way Hadoop clusters manage "trust" between servers and services, via **delegation tokens** >> the client authenticates against one service instance with Kerberos, then only uses tokens to interact with the cluster (explicitly with Java API, or via a session cookie with UIs and REST API). The Spark launcher, for instance, retrieves tokens for HDFS/YARN + optionally Hive + optionally HBase, then negotiates with YARN to start the job, then uploads tokens to its driver which uploads it to its executors.

Comment: In other words: use Keycloak to authenticate the client with Kerberos (if that's your requirement) then use some other mechanism that was designed for distributed systems e.g. JWT tokens.